# Can I query DAX (DynamoDB Accelerator) from an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Can someone help me out? I am trying to query DAX from EC2 to see how fast it is when they are in the same region (us-east-1)

```
    aws dynamodb query --endpoint-url \
    http://mydax.abcd.clustercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:8111 \
    --table-name test_1.0 --key-condition-expression 
    ...
```

security group of DAX has 80/443/8111 port open

I am getting this error:

> 2018-09-12 12:43:59,678 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG -
>   Exception received when sending HTTP request.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py",
>   line 174, in _get_response
>
> http_response = self._send(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py",
>   line 218, in _send
>
> return self.http_session.send(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py",
>   line 260, in send
>
> raise SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
>
> SSLError: SSL validation failed for
>   http://mydax.abcd.clustercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:8111/ EOF
>   occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)

Any hint guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use AWS DynamoDB CLI to connect to DAX clusters. DAX uses a custom binary protocol that is not based on http. DAX has its own clients which you can find [here](http://dax-sdk.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com).